# Is 1 hour and 15 minutes enough for transit in Amsterdam airport?

Tags: transit, amsterdam, ams, klm

I have a D type Schengen visa of Germany. I booked a ticket from KLM website itself from Istanbul to berlin. The issue is my passport would be checked in Amesterdam and stamped I think. I am not going to take my luggage since it is one time ticket and I will get two tickets from departure in Istanbul. The issue is my layover is 1 hour and 15 minutes. since I am going just in transit but my passport will be stamped is it enough?

I asked KLM they said that no problem. however, I really am not sure for this. If delayed what happened or if took more than expected? The next flight is 18 hours later which is really boring.

Any idea?

Comment: For clarity, are both legs booked on a single PNR with KLM?

Comment: When is this? The issue I see these days is more about Covid-related checks and so on which in some places introduce huge delays, not sure if those would affect passengers in non-Schengen-to-Schengen transit.

Comment: Hello. Yes all of them by KLM. single pnr

Comment: Their answer :  The amount of time needed varies from situation to situation, we consider anything under 60 minutes short connection time. For passengers who have a short connection we have special short connection passes, which gain them priority over "normal passengers."

Comment: anybody know how can I find short connection in the airport. i JUST FOLLOW THE TRANSIT right?

Comment: The normal rule is that if they sell it to you, they expect you should be able to do it, and if you don't, they'll put you on the next flight. In normal times, it should be plenty of time AND if you miss your flight, the next one is a short time later. In these times, it can indeed be a bit more tricky.

Comment: This connection won't work every time but more than 99% of the times. If the 18 hour wait is a catastrophe for you, you should try to find another flight. If not, it is worth the risk. Also note that the airline could choose to delay the second flight a bit if that is all needed for you (and maybe others) to make it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will be fine assuming you have the proper documents for entry (the German long-term "D" visa is listed as an exception allowing you to enter / transit through the Netherlands according to [IATA TravelCentre](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php)) and regarding Covid regulations (I haven't checked these for your specific situation).

I've arrived at Schiphol (as my final destination) from a non-safe country outside the EU a few weeks ago; I think I can give you some information on what to expect. Before disembarking the plane, we were told to have our passports and Covid tests ready. As soon as we disembarked the plane there were some marechaussees who glanced over our passports and Covid related documents. This all went pretty fast, and I don't think you'll have trouble here when you have your documents ready and complete.

After that, you can go straight to the transfer section (I assume there will be a security check after which you go through passport control). I recall walking past that and there were no queues, just an employee asking if anyone had a transfer flight. This gives me the impression that while there may be some extra checks related to Covid, the lack of queues (because passenger numbers are down by a lot) allow you to go to your connecting flight without delay.

There are also plenty of employees around the transfer / passport control area who seemed to be bored by the low passenger volume. If you feel you're having to wait too long or if you're close to your scheduled departure time (within 45 minutes?), you could wave to them and say that you've got a short connection. If you have your ticket ready and you are running late, they'll probably help you move along past the queue.

---

> I asked KLM they said that no problem. however, I really am not sure for this. If delayed what happened or if took more than expected? The next flight is 18 hours later which is really boring.

If that really bothers you then I think you could opt to leave Schiphol (assuming you meet the criteria to enter the Netherlands, which are a bit stricter than the criteria for transiting only) and take the [train from Schiphol to Berlin](https://www.nsinternational.com/en/traintickets-v3/#/search/NLSHL/DEBHF?pax=A) (no direct connections). Since you have no checked-in luggage, you wouldn't have to worry about that. You just have to check if your Covid documents allow you to enter Germany via train as well (e.g. is the time of taking / issuing of your test still within the regulations set by Germany considering the new timetable).

In any case, this is more of a backup plan if you were put on a later flight with a really long wait. If everything goes according to plan then you won't have to worry about this. If it puts your mind at ease then it might be worth looking at the train schedule and doing a bit of research on how to buy tickets for that journey at Schiphol's train station.

Comment: sir. I will come from istanbul. It is written if you come from non safe country and go to  other EU country just one test is enough. My flight is like this right? I mean I have a transit one right? Istanbul amsterdam warsaw with single booking klm

Comment: @Turkan I'm not sure if the transit situation changes the testing requirements. The normal testing requirements for the Netherlands are that you have 1 test taken (not issued but when the swab is taken) within 24 hours of boarding or two tests where one is taken within 72 hours and the other (rapid test) is taken within 24 hours. See also [my answer here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/163616)

Comment: @Turkan ah yeah, it seems the requirements are less strict because you only transit in the Netherlands. I guess you also have to look at the German requirements, they require the test to be at most 48 hours old before arriving in Germany. So I guess that that's the deadline you should meet.

Comment: If you start your journey in a high-risk country and change planes in the Netherlands you will only need to show the results of an NAAT (PCR) test based on a sample collected no more than 72 hours before arrival in the Netherlands.

Comment: @Turkan note though that Germany seems to allow antigen tests as well, but the Netherlands only allows only specific types of tests even for transit pasgangers. See [IATA travelcentre (click on the Netherlands / Germany)](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php) for the specifics.

Comment: https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/checklist

Comment: @Turkan yea those are the requirements for the Netherlands, so that's the NAAT test within 72 hours of arriving in the Netherlands. But for Germany, you also need a test taken within 48 hours of arriving in Germany (if I'm reading in correctly). So that's a tighter window.

Comment: So sirI am considered as a transfer right since I booked single with klm.

Comment: air I can use the same test in germany right? It is inside 48 hours

Comment: @Turkan yes, if the time between taking the test and your scheduled arrival is less than 48 hours then you will be fine. Just make sure to have an NAAT (PCR) test, that's required for the Netherlands (and also works for Germany). Germany also lists antigen tests, but the Netherlands doesn't accept antigen tests on their own.

Comment: I have one more question. If there is a 10 days quarantine in Germany how the police knows that person enters germany? I do not want to disobey the rule just as a curiosity. since the police just check in netherland