# Do I need to get a COVID-19 test when flying from Italy to the Netherlands?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, europe, covid-19, netherlands

I am planning to travel from Bergamo to Eindhaven with Ryanair. Do I have to take a COVID-19 test? If yes, do I need a PCR test or a rapid antigen swab?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need a Covid test. Depending on the time between taking the test and arriving in the Netherlands, you might actually need two. According to [government.nl](https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/mandatory-negative-test-results-and-declaration/requirements-pcr-test-result):

> If you are aged 13 or over and travelling to the Netherlands from a high-risk country, you must provide proof that you have tested negative for COVID-19. You can do this by presenting a negative NAAT (PCR) test result based on a sample collected no more than 24 hours before boarding the aircraft or ferry. Or you can present both a negative NAAT (PCR) test result based on a sample collected no more than 72 hours before arrival in the Netherlands and a negative rapid test result based on a sample collected no more than 24 hours before boarding. A negative rapid test result is not mandatory if you are travelling to the Netherlands by car, coach or train.

The Dutch government [provides a list of testing locations in Italy](https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/documents/publications/2021/02/01/italy---pcr-and-rapid-test-locations). I think these are just recommended locations, but you may also want to check the requirements on how the testing results are reported. These [requirements are](https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/mandatory-negative-test-results-and-declaration/requirements-pcr-test-result):

> The negative test result must be in English, German, French, Italian, Portuguese, Spanish or Dutch. A translation of the test result will be accepted provided the translation bears the original signature or stamp of the doctor or institute that conducted the test.
>
> The document must include the following information:
>
> - Type of test: the test used must be a molecular NAAT (PCR) test (either PCR, RT PCR, LAMP, TMA or mPOCT). No other type of test, including antigen tests and serological tests (blood tests to detect antibodies), is valid;
> - Test result: the test result must be negative (or ‘not detected’);
> - Your given name and surname as stated in your passport;
> - Date and time you were tested: the test sample must have been collected no more than 72 hours prior to arrival in the Netherlands;
> - Name and contact information of the institute or laboratory that conducted the test.